# How to proof tautology without truth table in this case?

Tags: boolean-algebra

Hej, i got stucked while finding a solution to proof the following is a tautology. Can someone help me out please with a good tip?
[image: My solution so far....]
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back up a step to $$(\overline{\overline{p}\lor q})\lor(\overline{\overline{q}\lor p})\lor(\overline{p}\lor q)\;;$$ you can rewrite it as

$$\left((\overline{\overline{p}\lor q})\lor(\overline{p}\lor q)\right)\lor(\overline{\overline{q}\lor p})\equiv\top\lor(\overline{\overline{q}\lor p})\equiv\top$$

via the law $\overline{x}\lor x\equiv\top$ and the absorption law $\top\lor x\equiv\top$.

Comment: @radscheit: You’re very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the equivalence between $(\lnot p \lor q)$ and $p \rightarrow q$.

With it, from your second line, we have :

> $[(p \rightarrow q) \land (q \rightarrow  p)] \rightarrow (p \rightarrow q)$

that is an instance of the rule of [Simplification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplification) : $(P \land Q) \rightarrow P$.

Comment: Probably no need for the first reference: the OP has already used that equivalence (Umformung der Implikation in die disjunktive Normalform).